# How to test a search engine?

Tags: manual-testing, testcase

My company has developed a search engine and handed over to the testing to test. I have no idea how to start. Its taking results from bing API

Comment: This isn't really enough for a full answer, but comparing to other search engines is probably a good start.

Answer (score 2):

What are the functional requirements on the search machine? Same results as Bing? Certain adds?
What are the qualitative requirements? Response time? Layout?

As soon as you know what was to be developed, you know what to test with what test goals. Afterwards, you can think about how to test it.

Comment: we don't have a much functional requirement. Results will be same as Bing. Adds has not been added as of now. response time is 30 second for returning particular result. static layout

Comment: Result should match Bing therefore is an implicit functional requirement. Do a back-to-back test with Bings search results on representative search items. You could start with the most popular search phrases. But I've not really asked for your response time and layout, but gave you a hint how to approach the problem. Layout and response time have just been examples

Comment: Results relevance is just one of the aspects of search engine. Another is presentation of result, e.g., whether result snippets with highlighted query keywords summarize the result well. This is important, because based on this snippets user taking is making a decision whether or not check the suggested page.

Comment: @user7699 You probably have functional requirements, they're just not enumerated. Someone somewhere wanted this thing to be built in order to serve a specific purpose; otherwise, a paper drawing of the Google homepage would suffice. Find out who they are, sit down with them, and ask them what they want. You'll probably hear things like "it works" and "it works quickly" -- there's two requirements already, that can be broken down further.

Comment: I would also not spend a lot of resources testing that the results match what you would get from Bing.  That is something that deserves some spot checking, and that's it.  Otherwise you will be getting into testing the Bing service, which you would hope Microsoft has already done sufficiently.  You are not technically testing a "Search Engine", you're testing the presentation of search results built on an existing already tested engine.

Comment: @SamWoods Correct. Some values suffice to test the correct use of the API. Most of the rest is qualitative requirements on the verge of functionality

Answer (score 0):

http://tools.seobook.com/general/spider-test/

Try above tool i think it will be useful for your testing process